# Excel VBA: When adding shapes to worksheet, locations are just a little bit off

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

So I'm creating a spreadsheet that will lookup a column header and add a shape to the cell in a certain row below the column header.  However, when I run the code, the shapes with smaller column numbers (closer to the origin) are pretty close, but shapes out in columns 30+ have a bit of error and are slightly off of where they ought to be.  Here's my code.

```
Public Function Drawshape(ByVal shaperow As Integer, ByVal thisrow As Integer, shapecase As      Integer)
Dim shpcol As Integer
Dim shpleft As Double
Dim shptop As Double
Dim shpwidth As Double
Dim shpheight As Double

'the columns are the day part of a date, so I find the cell that is "x" right of 
'the first date, where "x" is calculated based on another sheet.
shpcol = DateDiff("d", Sheet1.Cells(2, 2), Sheet1.Cells(thisrow, 9 + shapecase)) + 2
shpleft = Sheet2.Cells(shaperow, shpcol).Left
shptop = Sheet2.Cells(shaperow, shpcol).Top
shpwidth = Sheet2.Cells(shaperow, shpcol).Width
shpheight = Sheet2.Cells(shaperow, shpcol).Height

'depending on what shapecase is, the date I get is different, and the output shape is different
Select Case shapecase
    Case 0
        Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, shpleft, shptop, shpwidth, shpheight).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Case 1
        Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, shpleft, shptop, shpwidth, shpheight).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Case 2
        Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, shpleft, shptop, shpwidth, shpheight).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Case 3
        Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, shpleft, shptop, shpwidth, shpheight).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Shapes failed"
End Select
End Function
```

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, and I'm really hoping this is not an Excel bug...

When I try:

```
Debug.Print Sheet2.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 1744").Left
Debug.Print Sheet2.Range("BG10").Left       'The cell where the shape is supposed to live
```

I get 
1425.333 
1416

Comment: when you say they are off, off by how much?  if you count the number of cells to that point, say 10 cells, are you off by 10 pixels? Are there borders?

Comment: I edited the original post.  My cells are pretty small.  On the far right side of my spreadsheet the offset ends up being about half the size of the shape (about a 1/4" at 100% zoom, for reference)

Comment: I can't reproduce. Create a new workbook and execute this: `For i = 1 To 50: Me.Shapes.AddShape msoShape16pointStar, Me.Cells(i, i).Left, Me.Cells(i, i).Top, Me.Cells(i, i).Width, Me.Cells(i, i).Height: Next`. What do you get?

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, that helped a lot.  I couldn't reproduce it either in a blank spreadsheet.  I don't know why.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I may have come up with the answer, even if it's not a very satisfactory one.  Thanks to the testing suggestion provided by GSerg, I got to fiddling around with things.  I discovered that when I selected all cells (by clicking the upper left corner of the spreadsheet) and sized them all at the same time, I could affect the offset.  If I made the cells too narrow, the shapes would be offset left of where they should be.  If I made the cells too wide, the shapes would offset right of where they should be.  Similar effects occurred for the vertical dimensions too.

Interestingly, if i sized all the cells in this manner until the shapes matched up and then selected individual columns to resize, this had no effect on the offset.

I don't know why this happens, and I don't know how that fixed it.  But my problem is gone now?  So... good job everybody?  I guess?  If anybody can answer with the reason why this happens, I'll gladly still declare them the victor for this question.